# Как вывести json c русскими буквами

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

С самого начала я хотел из таблицы взять массив, который является json-массивом, но у меня не получилось. Я попробовал вывести при `json_encode` массив вручную записанный.

```php
$arr_tags = ['IT','Инвестиции','Amazon'];
$arr_tags =  json_encode($arr_tags);
var_dump($arr_tags);
```

Получился такой результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Получается, что мне придётся в таблице хранить такой результат в формате `unicode`, но есть способ, чтобы поддерживались русские буквы? Чтобы я взял значение из таблицы с русскими буквами, сделал `json_decode` и вывел значения массива

Comment: Это абсолютно нормальные экранированные русские буквы, ничего исправлять не требуется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP  json_encode есть флаг JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```